# JAXWS problem without namespace prefix using Jboss 4.2.3ga

Tags: web-services, jboss, jax-ws, xml-namespaces

I have a java service published as a JAXWS webservice using @WebServiceannotation. The service is well deployed on Jboss application server 4.2.3ga (with Jax-ws implementation provided by the application server).

The service works well when the Soap message look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pref="mynamespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <pref:mymethod>
            <arg0>value</arg0>
        </pref:mymethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And failed when the Soap message look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="mynamespace">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
        <mymethod>
            <arg0>value</arg0>
        </mymethod>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

By fail I mean "mymethod" is invoked, but arg0 is null.

Does anybody know if it is the expected behaviour of JAX-WS api or a bug ? I found no reference to one or to the other.

Does anybody experienced the same problem (or success) using another JAX-WS stack ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the working code there is no default namespace and `<mymethod>` is bound to `mynamespace` with a prefix. 
Because the `<arg0>` element has no prefix, it is in **null namespace**.

In the failing code `mynamespace` is set as the default namespace. Because `<mymethod>` and `<arg0>` do not have any prefix, they **both** have `mynamespace` as their namespace URI.

It is not allowed to bind the empty namespace URI to any prefix. Therefore you either need to continue to use a namespace prefix in `<mymethod>` or you need to override the default namespace in `<arg0>` like this:

```
<arg0 xmlns="">
```

Note that this sets all the unprefixed child elements of `<arg0>` to null namespace unless you override the default namespace again.